# Indy10 problem connecting to TCP Server using a host name pointing to an IPv6 address

Tags: delphi-7, ipv6, indy10

I've put the following in the Windows `HOSTS` file:

```
fe80::a5c6:d354:8e27:9f79%16 ip6test
```

I can ping `ip6test` in Windows, and I can connect to a server via `TIdTCPClient` with the IPv6 address above in square brackets, but trying to connect using the host name `[ip6test]` using the TCP Client instantly fails with a socket error 11001.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bracket workaround only works in `TIdHTTP`. Don't use it with `TIdTCPClient`.

For `TIdTCPClient`, you have to set its `IPVersion` property to `Id_IPv6` when connecting to an IPv6 server. It is not yet smart enough to detect which IP
version an IP address is using, or which IP version(s) a hostname resolves to, so you have to tell it up front (this will be addressed in a future release).

For example, a simple workaround would look like this:

```
Client.Host := ...; 
Client.Port := ...;

if (Client.Host is an IPv4 address) then
begin
  Client.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  Client.Connect;
end
else if (Client.Host is an IPv6 address) then
begin
  Client.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
  Client.Connect;
end
else
begin
  try
    // try to connect with IPv6 first...
    Client.IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
    Client.Connect;
  except
    // try again with IPv4...
    Client.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
    Client.Connect;
  end;

  // alternatively, you can use TIdDNSResolver
  // beforehand to resolve the hostname
  // yourself, and then setup TIdTCPClient
  // accordingly... 
end;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize some years ago I had already added a test for the first character being a '[' and selecting IPv6.  This works without removing the brackets when it's an IP address but doesn't work with a host name.  I'm not sure why.  I've now modified the code to remove the brackets after switching to IPVersion to IPv6 and its working.  Thank you.